# Compile Java in Xcode 4

Tags: java, xcode, macos, compiler-construction

I know that this question has been floating around for ages now ...

**Java in Xcode 4**.

I don't need any recommendations (Eclipse, Netbeans e.g.) I just want to compile some simple Java Code in "XCode4" (not 3). I managed to create a File and as expected the syntax and everything works but the Compiler due to the missing Scheme. I am kinda stuck at the executable.

My Question is:

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

**YES this is possible.**

```
    1) File > New > New Project > Other > External Build System
    2) Give it some name and save it somewhere.
    3) File > New > New File > Other > Empty
    4) Give it a Java-friendly name. In my example, use "HelloWorld.java"
    5) Copy the contents below into the file and save.
    6) File > New > New File > Other > Empty
    7) Save as "Makefile".
    8) Copy the contents below into the file and save.
    9) The "Run" (>) button should at least compile your Java now.
```

Now it gets tricky. You don't have to do the next part. You could just open a Terminal to your project directory and run "java HelloWorld" if you want. I strongly suggest that. You can also just type "make" and use Xcode purely as a text editor.

```
    9) Project > Edit Scheme > Debug > Info
    10) Executable > Other > type ^⌘g > type "/bin" > choose "sh"
    11) Arguments
    12) Set "Base Expansion on" whatever you named your target
    13) Add an argument '-c "/usr/bin/java -classpath  $(PROJECT_DIR) HelloWorld"' for this example.
    14) Cross your fingers
    15) Click the "Run" (>) button.
```

*An Extract from* [Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3651347?start=0&tstart=0)