# XCode Error - Command /usr/bin/javac failed with exit code 2 - Java

Tags: java, ios, xcode

I am using XCode to compile and run a Java program. I have an error like this:

```
javac: file not found: .java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Command /usr/bin/javac failed with exit code 2
```

when I attempt to build the program. I thought that the error might I have been due to the fact that the name of my target and file are different, but both are file_name.java.

Could someone also explain how to run XCode with Java, without Terminal? I know there are questions like this already answered, but I have trouble after building the program (successfully).

Also, I did compile another program and the build succeeded, but there was no class file for it (file_name.class) in Finder.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946163/compile-java-in-xcode-4

Comment: Part of it, yes, I edited it and although I know how to compile it with Terminal, I am asking how to do so without Terminal - the main question is the first paragraph, not second.